# Why do these input fields fall down?

Tags: html, css, positioning

The two input fields [here](http://jsbin.com/epoqus/2) - why do they fall down, and don't render at the top?

The code:

```
<form style="height: 200px;display: block;">
  <span id="inputs" style="height: 100px;display: inline-block;">
    <input value="AAA" style="display: inline;">
    <input id="email" value="Your Email">
  </span>
  <div id="form-right-column" style="display: inline-block; width: 122px; height:50px; background-color:blue">
  </div>
</form>
```

People, please don't just post a solution, I'd like to really understand why this is happening, not just to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, adding `vertical-align: top;` to form-right-column seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use `vertical-align: top;` in `span` tag to render it on the top.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/epoqus/3

You need `vertical-align:top` Default value is like `baseline` or something